# While running, is it possible to display the currently allocated buffers managed by LeakSanitizer?

Tags: memory-leaks, address-sanitizer

I've a very large program (okay, only 13,000 lines of code according to `cloc`) which leaks. I know because over time, it uses more and more resident memory.

I have the sanitizer option turned on, but on a clean exit, all my C++ software will properly clean everything as expected. So I don't see anything growing in the sanitizer output.

What would be useful in this case, is a way to call a function which displays the (large) list of allocated buffers while running the code. I can then look at a diff of two such outputs and see what was allocated anew. The leaked buffers will be in there...

At this point, though, I just don't see any header with sanitizer functions I could call to see such a list. Does it exist?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Lsan interface is available in [sanitizer/lsan_interface.h](https://github.com/llvm-mirror/compiler-rt/blob/master/include/sanitizer/lsan_interface.h) but AFAIK it has no API to print allocation info. The best you can get is compile your code with Asan (which includes Lsan as well) and use `__asan_print_accumulated_stats` to get basic allocation statistics:

```
$ cat tmp.c
#include <sanitizer/asan_interface.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main() {
  malloc(100);
  __asan_print_accumulated_stats();
  return 0;
}
$ gcc -fsanitize=address -g tmp.c && ./a.out
Stats: 0M malloced (0M for red zones) by 2 calls
Stats: 0M realloced by 0 calls
Stats: 0M freed by 0 calls
Stats: 0M really freed by 0 calls
Stats: 0M (0M-0M) mmaped; 5 maps, 0 unmaps
  mallocs by size class: 7:1; 11:1;
Stats: malloc large: 0
Stats: StackDepot: 2 ids; 0M allocated
Stats: SizeClassAllocator64: 0M mapped in 256 allocations; remains 256
  07 (112): mapped: 64K allocs: 128 frees: 0 inuse: 128 num_freed_chunks 457 avail: 585 rss: 4K releases: 0
  11 (176): mapped: 64K allocs: 128 frees: 0 inuse: 128 num_freed_chunks 244 avail: 372 rss: 4K releases: 0
Stats: LargeMmapAllocator: allocated 0 times, remains 0 (0 K) max 0 M; by size logs:

=================================================================
==15060==ERROR: LeakSanitizer: detected memory leaks

Direct leak of 100 byte(s) in 1 object(s) allocated from:
    #0 0x7fdf2194fb40 in __interceptor_malloc (/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libasan.so.4+0xdeb40)
    #1 0x559ca08a7857 in main /home/yugr/tmp.c:5
    #2 0x7fdf214a1bf6 in __libc_start_main (/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libc.so.6+0x21bf6)

SUMMARY: AddressSanitizer: 100 byte(s) leaked in 1 allocation(s).
```

Unfortunately there is no way to print exact allocations.

Comment: Ah! I found the headers, its under `/usr/lib/gcc/...`. I looked, just in case, and I found `__lsan_do_leak_check()`, which is what the code calls before `exit()` (or around that time, at least), and another one `__lsan_do_recoverable_leak_check()`, which does exactly what I want! It prints out the leaks and goes on. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction.

Comment: @AlexisWilke right but `__lsan_do_recoverable_leak_check` does not do what you asked for - it does not print allocations or even alloc statistics like `__asan_print_accumulated_stats `. And given that all pointers are reachable (as you stated in your question), it shouldn't report any leaks at all. So all in all, I'm not sure how it can be useful to you.

Comment: @AlexisWilke note that there are other malloc tracing solutions e.g. [perf](https://www.brendangregg.com/FlameGraphs/memoryflamegraphs.html) or [Google heap profiler](https://gperftools.github.io/gperftools/heapprofile.html)

Comment: Well... too bad. The perf system uses kernel special features which are not compiled in by default on a Jetson board. So I'll pass on that one.